# How can I open Terminal with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: pantheon-terminal, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

How I can open terminal with a keyboard shortcut? I can't open terminal pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> in english layout. Can I assign my own keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To open terminal press <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Super key = Windows key

**EDIT**:

To customize your shortcut key:

Open **System settings** -- > **Keyboard** --> **Applications**

[image: Imgur]

Now  select `terminal` on right side of window, then just press the shortcut key you want to assign.

*For example*:

If you want to assign <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

After highlighting `terminal` on right side of window, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. That's it.

Comment: Can I define somehow, to open the terminal **always with focus**, too?