# Is there a task manager for elementary os freya?

Tags: release-freya, applications, pantheon-files, system

Is there an elementary os keyboard equivalent to windows ctlr+alt+del that would launch a task manager, process list, ability to set affinity, priority, kill a proces,monitor memory and cpu loads, + performance. Or which ubuntu/software task manager  can I install that is not going to break anything?

Comment: Are you _comfortable_ to use terminal (CLI)?

Comment: @jmarkus: As you're a reputation 11 user: If one of the answers below helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of its text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: Fabby - glad you pointed out this oversight on my part. I ticked all three responses, but it seems only one will stick. All were helpful. Any one of the three options work, and I have installed all three. I love efficiency and htop seems to have won that title, but for gui  system monitor seems best. YMMV

Answer (score 12, accepted):

elementary OS doesn't ship with a system monitor by default. I would recommend installing GNOME System Monitor from Software Center:

[image: GNOME System Monitor]

Comment: sorry, @Daniel why are you avoiding to give terminal command `sudo apt-get install gnome-system-monitor`. Just curious to know :)

Comment: Hey @Ravan this kind of discussion is not really appropriate for comments on an answer; it would be better suited to meta. But to answer your question, I don't think it's generally a good idea to condition new users to enter Terminal commands from the Internet. In fact, Terminal explicitly warns against it when you try. This is how a lot of people break their installs. Terminal is a developer's tool and isn't required to perform tasks like installing new apps.

Comment: thank you =) @DanielFore, I will post on meta, please answer :) I understand your point.

Comment: I request you please don't DV for CLI answers, (regarding htop), I clearly mentioned that is CLI.

Answer (score 6):

One of the GUI-based task manager is [LXTask](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXTask)

- Lightweight, simple
- Monitors processes
- Can kill processes
- Real GUI

*Installation*:

1. From Software Center

**Or**

2. From terminal:(If you are *comfortable* with terminal)

   ```
   sudo apt-get install lxtask
   ```

[image: Imgur]

Comment: It starts via Ctrl+Alt+Del (mentioned in [main page](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXTask)), (I have not tested to start using this shortcut since my keyboard Del key not working )

Comment: Installed both, and they seem pretty good. I would like a keystroke combo to launch one of them - should the plank become unresponsive. (It has due to high cpu usage of gala, but I think I have that solved now) Is there a way to assign ctrl+alt+del to launching Gnome system monitor, or lxtask?

Comment: yes =) @jmarkus let me try :)

Comment: @jmarkus you can try [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/552924/439451)

Comment: Worked great for creating another shortcut for the terminal. But for sytem monitor the terminal is saying this ** (gnome-system-monitor:6378): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-GKMKspk4te: Connection refused

** (gnome-system-monitor:6378): WARNING **: SELinux was found but is not enabled.

Comment: @jmarkus forget about warnings =)

Comment: @jmarkus for teminal shortcut see [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2816/how-can-i-open-terminal-with-a-keyboard-shortcut/2817#2817)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use *CLI*, you can use **htop**.

*Installation*:

1. From *Software Center*

**Or**

2. From terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install htop
   ```

To start *htop* you have to run `htop` in terminal.

It can list all the processes with CPU/RAM usage, Overall CPU/RAM usage and more. It can also kill a process. You have to use up and down arrow keys to navigate.

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Hey - that is slick! I think I'll make a shortcut to htop

Comment: If your computer is being slowed down by something, and you need a shortcut to get to it, you can switch to a terminal with `Ctrl+Alt+F1` (or F1-F6), and switch back with `Ctrl+Alt+F7` (which is the terminal that the OS's visuals/GUI, the X Window System server, uses).